# expose an Access database on a Linux web server

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, linux, ms-access, integration

I have a website hosted on a Linux server.  If someone sends me an Access database file, what would be a quick way to expose the data through a web user interface?  The Access data does not need to be kept up to date... it could be converted to something like `mySql` (don't know if that is possible/recommended) and the data maintained going forward in the "converted" database.

I don't have any Rails experience but from what I understand, this would be something doable using Rails (database-first design) and it would give me a chance to get my feet wet on Rails.  But I am open to any solution that would be free and run on Linux, including some sort of content management system.

I would like to have some kind of bare-bones security... i.e. "users A, B, and C have read-only access to the data; users X, Y, and Z can make changes".

Comment: Please specify which Ruby implementation you're running. If you're on JRuby you could use any Access JDBC driver.

Comment: Are you looking to do this dynamically?  Meaning, you receive Access databases, parse them and dump them to a real database?  Or are you simply using a single Access database to seed your application with its initial data?

Comment: just a 1-time receiving / conversion of the Access database

Comment: @Qwe, I'm not running any Ruby implementation... I can install whatever I want on my Linux server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution could be a tool to parse MS Access mdb files.
You could try http://mdbtools.sourceforge.net/

I found this good article: http://pnenp.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/converting-ms-access-mdb-files-to-sqlite-mdb2sqlite/ that explain how to convert a access db to sqlite.

Comment: But then what? How do I expose it on the web?

Comment: Once you converted your database to Sqlite, you can use sqlite with activerecords on Ruby on Rails. You have then to begin studying Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 1):

Use "access2mysql" (free) => make a MySQL version of your Access DB.

Comment: Do you have direct and recent experience with this product?